# Unity and MySQL can't register many Chinese

Tags: php, mysql, unity-game-engine

I am making register and log in .

When I input over two Chinese words , it's can't register.
Only one Chinese word can register.

I add the Chinese words to username from phpMyadmin and it can log in!

Why I can't register many Chinese at start?

please help me !

PHP:

```php
 <?php

 $con = mysqli_connect('xxxx:3306', 'root', 'xxxx', 'xxxx');

 if(mysqli_connect_errno())
 {
     echo "1: Connection failed";
     exit();
 }

 $username = $_POST["name"];
 $password = $_POST["password"];
 $gender = $_POST["gender"];


 $namecheckquery = "SELECT username FROM players WHERE username='" . $username . "';";

 $namecheck = mysqli_query($con, $namecheckquery) or die("2: Name check query failed");


 if (mysqli_num_rows($namecheck) > 0)
 {
     echo "3:Name already exists";
     exit();
 }

 $salt = "\$5\$rounds=5000\$" . "steamedhams" . $username . "\$";
 $hash = crypt($password, $salt);
 $insertuserquery = "INSERT INTO players (username, hash,salt,gender) VALUES 
  ('" . $username."', '" . $hash . "', '". $salt."','".$gender."');";
 mysqli_query($con, $insertuserquery) or die ("4: Insert player query failed");

 echo ("0"); ?>
```

My code in Unity

```c#
public class Registration : MonoBehaviour
{
    public InputField nameField;
    public InputField passwordField;

    public Button submitButton;
    public Button boyButton;
    public Button girlButton;

    public void CallRegister()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Register());
    }

    IEnumerator Register()
    {
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField("name", nameField.text);
        form.AddField("password", passwordField.text);

        WWW www = new WWW("http://localhost/sqlconnect/register.php", form);
        yield return www;
        if(www.text =="0")
        {
            Debug.Log("User created successfully");
            UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene("mainmenu");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("User creation failed. Error #" + www.text);
        }
    }

    public void VerifyInputs()
    {
        submitButton.interactable = (nameField.text.Length >= 1 && passwordField.text.Length >= 4);
    }
}
```

Comment: How is this related to Unity in the first place? As it is this question seems to be more about PHP, right? Otherwise please also add the Unity/c# part of your code

Comment: ok, I update C#  code.

Comment: @YvetteColomb would have been nice to also add the code provided by OP as answer (because he is new and isn't used to SO yet) to the question instead of only deleting it making him only more confused

Comment: Is it intended that you don't send the `gender` field? Also what do you mean by `I input over two Chinese words`? is it possible that the space is causing trouble here? Does it also happen if you input other words that are not Chinese? In general you should rather use [`UnityWebRequest.Post`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Post.html)

Comment: sorry , I'm new . so I am not familiar with this . I already change WWW to UnityWebRequest.Post.  _國 is one word,  so 國國 is two word_

Comment: For me those are two symbols ;) did you try it with other characters that are not Chinese? Maybe it is simply an encoding problem as said

Comment: The gender field is done. I think the problem is not here.

Comment: Like Japanese, に is one word , にに is two words . And the problem still there.

Comment: lol I ment maybe somthing that doesn't have asian special characters ;) as said I think it is a problem with the encoding

Comment: Could you test and add `echo($username)` after receiving the POST field in php? is the second character already missing there?

Comment: I use MySQL to insert the username . It's can work . I don't why it can't work in Unity

Comment: And I try other asian character ,there have same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but my guess would be that `WWW` does not automatically escape spaces in the provided `form` or have encoding errors.

In general you should try and rather use [`UnityWebRequest.Post`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Post.html) which clearly states:

> The data in postData will be escaped, then interpreted into a byte stream via `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8`.

which might solve your problem

```
private IEnumerator Register()
{
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("name", nameField.text);
    form.AddField("password", passwordField.text);

    using(var www = UnityWebRequest.Post("http://localhost/sqlconnect/register.php", form))
    {
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.Log(www.error);
            return;
        }

        if(string.Equals(www.downloadHandler.text, "0"))
        {
            Debug.Log("User created successfully");
            UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene("mainmenu");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("User creation failed. Error #" + www.text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I use `UnityWebRequest.Postˋ , it's still not  work.